# .Net core docker build with multiple projects

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-build

Net core project and I have many webapi, business layer and some other layers here. Below is the folder stucture.

> Main Solution
>
> 1. businessLayer
> 2. data layer
> 3. Web API layer
>    3.1 MyDockerFile

Below is my docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ["Enrichment.WebApi/Enrichment.WebApi.csproj", "Enrichment.WebApi/"]
COPY ["Enrichment.Facade/Enrichment.Facade.csproj", "Enrichment.Facade/"]
COPY ["Enrichment.Saga/Enrichment.Saga.csproj", "Enrichment.Saga/"]
COPY ["Enrichment.BusinessModel/Enrichment.BusinessModel.csproj", "Enrichment.BusinessModel/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Enrichment.WebApi/Enrichment.WebApi.csproj"

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Enrichment.WebApi.dll"]
```

When I run docker build -t enrichment.webapi . I get below output

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  230.8MB
Step 1/16 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
 ---> 9a88f73dec65
Step 2/16 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b50f1fc6721
Step 3/16 : COPY ["Enrichment.WebApi/Enrichment.WebApi.csproj", "Enrichment.WebApi/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder437963979/Enrichment.WebApi/Enrichment.WebApi.csproj: no such file or directory
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting above error. Path looks like incorrect but I am not able to understand what would be the right path. can someone help me to understand any issue here. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try this copy command: COPY . WebApp1/

Comment: Try this build command: docker build -t webapi -f Dockerfile ..

Comment: This command worked for copying but started getting error Step 9/16 : COPY *.csproj ./
COPY failed: no source files were specified

Comment: Hi Ashik Thanks for your answer. First errors went but started getting error in the line of dockerfile COPY *.csproj ./.

Comment: can upvote the comment which resolved your previous error

Answer (score 0):

```
Step 9/16 : COPY *.csproj ./ COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

This is because of `.dockerignore` file that ignores the `csproj`. Notice the content of `.dockerignore` below and Anything other than `obj/Docker/publish/*` and `obj/Docker/empty` is ignored.

```
*
!obj/Docker/publish/*
!obj/Docker/empty/
```

Incude this in your dockerfile

```
# build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out ./
```

Comment: Hi Ashok Above lines already I have in my dockerfile If you see above dockerfile

Comment: Once check the copy command and add a leading slash

Comment: Yeah correct. I changed that but I am getting error just above in COPY *.csproj ./